# Configuring Plex for streaming live radio

Tags: audio-streaming, plex

I would like to stream the classical station [WCPE](https://theclassicalstation.org/internet.shtml) through Plex.  I have tried [this plugin](https://github.com/WBGSReject/plex-plugin-theoldradioset) with no success and then I tried the suggestions in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/2g0l5p/set_up_your_pms_to_serve_live_amfm_radio_streams/), also with no success.  Last, I tried [another reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/6g41lz/best_way_to_get_internet_radio_through_plex_in/) (sort of, since there is a 2017 version of the plugin which has a different file structure) and that *still* doesn't work.  Clearly, my googling is not very productive right now.

I am looking for specific instructions on how to stream the aforementioned station (any quality at the moment, although I'd prefer the 128 aac stream if possible).  I am running Plex on a Raspberry Pi, and have updated everything to the latest (as of October 2018) versions.